# blob file get unauthorized access error when downloaded from client pc

Tags: javascript, c#

```
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.example.com" + file, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/zip");
    xhttp.responseType = "blob";
    xhttp.onload = function (event) {
        var blob = xhttp.response;
        //checking file size
        var blobSize = xhttp.response.size;
         (xhttp.response.size > 0) {
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/plain', link.download, link.href].join(':');
            link.download = fileName;
            link.click();
        }
```

I have deployed it on a server but when I try to access that from the server, the zip files download without any problem. When I try to download from client-server, the file gets corrupted.

The file can be only downloaded with the server's approved IP address. I assume when I try to download the file on the client side, the file doesn't pass through the server IP address.

Comment: you say `the file gets corrupted`. in what way is it corrupted? Have you checked the browser developer tools? is the content length correct? is the response content-type what you expect? why are you setting the **request** `content-type` to `application/zip` - makes no sense for a GET request to have a `content-type` since you don't send any content in a GET request

Comment: File doesn't get corrupted when accessed from the deployed server. I removed the content-type too, but it didn't make any impact. the zip file still get corrupted when downloaded from the client-server.

Comment: in what way is it corrupted? too short? too long? wrong contents? details help debugging

Comment: The chrome debugging error says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()", it only happens on the client pc. But when I try to access that application via hosted server, it file gets downloaded. This is because the URL is whitelisted for the hosted server only. I was wondering why i am not able to download the file on the client's server. I want the URL file to be downloaded using hosted server IP on the client's pc.  Is there any way to specify the hosted server prox when a get request is made?

Comment: so, it's not corrupted after all - you have an unauthorized client error status response - this  indicates that the request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource

Comment: You may want to change the question to indicate that the issue is not "corruption" - it's a simple unauthorized access error - perhaps you can fix that, now that you know the problem is completely different to what you thought it was

Comment: can you suggest me something? The file should be downloaded as it downloads on the hosted server. is there anything I can do to add hosted server information before a GET request is being send on the client's server?

Comment: *can you suggest me something?* debug the issue you have, rather than the issue you thought you had - the issue is authorization related - is it your server you're requesting to

Comment: yes, is there any way to authorization the server before making xhttp.open request?

Comment: probably - is it your server? you should know how to do that

Comment: yes, i guess know I see CORS policy error when i added xhttp.withCredentials = true; to the code.

Comment: you're getting there - now all you need is to fix the CORS error and you're done